# Flink - how to compute sum and average at the same time?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is there a way in Flink (batch/streaming) to compute the average and sum of a field at the same time? Using the aggregate method I can compute the sum of a field on a groupBy result, but how do I calculate the average also at the same time? Example code below.

```
ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
DataSet<Tuple3<String,Integer,Double>> source = 
         env.readCsvFile(PathConfig.LINEITEM_1)
         .fieldDelimiter("|")
         types(String.class, Integer.class, Double.class);

source.groupBy(0,1).aggregate(Aggregations.SUM, 2);
//average of field 2???
```

Comment: Could you use map/reduce instead of aggregate ?

Comment: I could use reduceGroup to calculate both sum and average manually, but since there is already a nice aggregate sum function, I thought maybe there is also a way to calculate the average automatically.

Answer (score 2):

For simple tasks like CSV parsing, grouping, and aggregating I would recommend to use Flink's [Table API](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/dev/table_api.html).

If you rather want to use more low-level APIs, you can implement a [`GroupReduce`](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/dev/batch/dataset_transformations.html#groupreduce-on-grouped-dataset) function that sums/counts (until the iterator has no more elements) and produces a final average at the end.

Comment: I'm somehow unsure of using the Table API, because it seems to have a lot of limitations (like no joins for streaming tables). I'm just wondering if there is a readily method to compute the average, because it should be just a simple aggregate function, right? I saw in the older source code that there was indeed an average aggregate function but it was commented out in the new version, I wonder why is that...

Comment: Yes, it has limitations, but since you can go back and forth between DataStream and Table, it is a pretty useful tool. See also: http://flink.apache.org/news/2017/03/29/table-sql-api-update.html
Averaging seems easy but it requires two operations (a aggregation step and a final map for division) and the return type depends on the input. It is better to let the user implement what he/she needs.